# Comparing character inputs read from stdin

Tags: c, char, compare, strcmp

I am trying to debug a program which were I am getting the values 'S' or 'P' from standard input. My function `calc_resistance()` needs to distinguish between these two cases as well as a case were neither `'S'` nor `'P'` has been entered. The program always evaluates to the third case (neither `'S'` nor 'P'`), why is this so?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

float calc_resistance(char conn) {

float retval = 0.0;

 if (conn == 'S') {
   retval = 1;
 }
 else if (conn == 'P') { 
   retval = 2;
 }
 else {
   retval = -1;
 }
 return retval;
}

int main() {
  char connection_type[25];
  float resistance = 0.0;

  while(1) {
    printf("Enter 'S' or 'P': ");
    scanf("%s", connection_type);
    if(strlen(connection_type) != 1 ||
       (strncmp(connection_type,"S",25) && strncmp(connection_type,"P",25))) {
      printf("Answer not understood. Enter 'S' or 'P'.\n");
      continue;
    }
    break;
 }

  resistance = calc_resistance(connection_type);

  printf("Connection type: %f", resistance);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The mistake you're doing is to pass an array to the `calc_resistance()` function when it is defined to accept only a single `char`.

Seeing the input pattern, `connection_type` doesn't need to be an array, with the help of `%c` format specifier, you can easily make `connection_type` a single `char` variable to work on the input.

You can read more about this on the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) of `scanf()`. Also, after each iteration, don't forget to sweep out the remaining *newline*.

*Moral of the story :: Enable compiler warnings and pay heed to them.*

Answer (score 0):

You want to detect the first two cases right? if yes then try this one instead of passing the whole address in your function

```
 calc_resistance(connection_type)
```

only pass one character then try, You can modify the code as below.

```
    #include 
    #include 
    #include 

    float calc_resistance(char conn)
    {

            float retval = 0.0;

            if (conn == 'S')
            {
                    retval = 1;
            }
            else if (conn == 'P')
             {
                    retval = 2;
            }
            else
            {
                    retval = -1;
            }
            return retval;
    }

    int main()
    {
            char connection_type[25];
            float resistance = 0.0;

            while(1)
            {
                    printf("Enter 'S' or 'P': ");
                    scanf("%s", connection_type);

                    if (strlen(connection_type) != 1 || (strncmp(connection_type,"S",25) && strncmp(connection_type,"P",25)))
                    {
                            printf("Answer not understood. Enter 'S' or 'P'.\n");
                            continue;
                    }
                    break;
            }

            resistance = calc_resistance(connection_type[0]);

            printf("Connection type: %f", resistance);

    }
```